# how to set parameters simulation of wirelesses sensors in ns2

Tags: ns2

i want to know how to setup parameters and values of simulation for Wireless Sensor Networks like :

channel type

radio-propagation model

network interface type

MAC type

interface queue type

link layer type

antenna model

max packet in ifq

please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

## Define how a mobile node should be created

```
$ns_ node-config -adhocRouting DSDV\
     -llType LL \
     -macType Mac/802_11\
     -ifqLen 50 \
     -ifqType Queue/DropTail/PriQueue \
     -antType Antenna/OmniAntenna \
     -propType Propagation/TwoRayGround \
     -phyType Phy/WirelessPhy \
     -channelType Channel/WirelessChannel \
     -topoInstance $topo
     -agentTrace ON \
     -routerTrace OFF \
     -macTrace OFF
```